# Cannot remove event count in angular-calendar

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I am using angular calendar https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar
And I am trying to remove the total event counts from the calendar.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jitLN.png)
I have set encapsulation: `ViewEncapsulation.None` on my component file and my css file looks:

```
.cal-day-badge{
    display: none;
}
```

But the css is not overwritten. I tried it on `.cal-month-view` and it worked fine but did not work on `.cal-day-badge`

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .cal-day-badge {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)